# Add one winform to another project

Tags: c#, winforms, project

I have 3 projects, I want to merge the winforms in each project into one project. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to analyse if forms in those 3 projects has any not standard dependencies (references to libraries). Then you can create new project, add library references from other projects, drag and drop files from old projects to new project, fix namespaces (or preserve them so you dont have collision between similar forms or names from different projects)

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward approach would be:

- Create new Project
- Copy all needed code files in Solution Explorer to the new project
- Fix namespaces
- Add missing references (if any)
- Drop original projects

Comment: My namespace and class is same in the form. how do i change the namespace or class, so i will be able to create a type out of the class. it doesnt let me

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new project
2. In Solution Explorer click Add Existing Items.
3. Add all the forms from different projects (Make sure that name of each form should be different.)

Comment: would it create any conflicts? i did what you said, but then dragged the forms to another project!! so what i got, 3 projects in one solution explorer and under one project i have 3 forms (i dragged them).

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't used it before, JetBrain's Resharper could be very useful for you in this case.

To rename the namespace, click on the namespace on the class and hit F2 (hope it works without Resharper).